# Parsing out multiple API JSON response parameters

Tags: ruby, json, api, parsing

I'm getting a JSON response back from an API, however the response has several key parameters all called 'jacket' with different values. I am able to parse out the first key but I don't get the rest of the values. Here is some of the code, I might be approaching this the wrong way:

```
parsed_list = JSON.parse(get_response.body) 
orig = parsed_list["_links"]["stuff"]["orig"]
serv = parsed_list["_links"]["stuff"]["serv"]
puts orig.first["jacket"]
puts serv.first["jacket"]

=> 123456789
=> 987654321
```

This is what the JSON response looks like before I parse it out and set it "parsed_list"

```
    "_links": {
"self": {
  "href": "url"
},
"stuff": {
  "href": "url",
  "orig": [
    {
      "jacket": "123456789",
      "Id": "x",
      "selected": true,
    }
  ],
  "serv": [
    {
      "jacket": "987654321",
      "Id": "xx",
      "selected": false,
    },
    {
       "jacket": "0000000001",
      "Id": "xx",
      "selected": false,
    },
    {
       "jacket": "1111111110",
      "Id": "xx",
      "selected": false,
    }
  ]
 }
}
}
```

I need to be able to extract all of the "jacket" values.

Comment: How are you trying to get the rest of the values?  Certainly not with `first`.  Also, edit your question to clean up the raw JSON's formatting -- the dangling "}}" after the code block.

Comment: oops, sorry, overlooked that; fixed. I ended up using .first because without it I was getting error `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError). I'm stuck on figuring out how to get the rest of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data's right there, you just need to get it:

```
serv.collect do |entry|
  entry['jacket']
end
```

Comment: There's a lot of good stuff in the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html) module that's worth familiarizing yourself with. It's quite a toolbox.